# How can I improve my table in order to use count function effectively

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, count

I have two tables, a survey table and a property table, I'm trying to write a select script that will show a list of properties with the number of surveys that were carried out on each.
At first I just added an attribute to my survey entity stating the number of surveys and so I could write a simple script. 
Eg.

```
SELECT Property_Address, No_of_Survey
FROM Property, Survey 
WHERE Property.Property_ID = Survey.Property_ID;
```

However as I’m new to this, I soon realised that this is poor design because the user would have to update the number of surveys each time whereas the database should be making the calculations. 
So then I thought that my select query should really be using a count function and now I’ve just confused myself completely!
I have come up with a query but it’s not working, stating that the column is ambiguously defined. Here is my new script;

```
SELECT Property_Address, COUNT(Survey_ID) AS SurveyCount
FROM Property, Survey
WHERE Property_ID.Property_ID = Survey.Property_ID
GROUP by property_ID;
```

I’m really looking to know if my create tables need to be altered so that my query works as intended or if the query just needs to be altered.

Here are my tables;

```
CREATE TABLE Property 
(
Property_ID varchar(5),                              
Property_Address varchar(25),
Property_Town varchar(25),
Property_Postcode varchar(25),                       
Asking_Price varchar2(20),                           
Date_Registered DATE,                                
Property_Type varchar2(50),                          
Num_Rooms varchar2(50),                              
Buyer_ID varchar(5),                                 
Seller_ID varchar(5),                                
Branch_ID varchar(5),                                
PRIMARY KEY (Property_ID),                           
FOREIGN KEY (Buyer_ID) REFERENCES Buyer(Buyer_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Seller_ID) REFERENCES Seller(Seller_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Branch_ID) REFERENCES Branch(Branch_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Survey 
(                                                          
Survey_ID varchar(5),                                      
No_of_Survey varchar2(10),                                 
Survey_Type varchar2(50),                                  
Property_ID varchar(5),                                    
Buyer_ID varchar(5),                                       
PRIMARY KEY (Survey_ID),                                   
FOREIGN KEY (Property_ID) REFERENCES Property(Property_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Buyer_ID) REFERENCES Buyer(Buyer_Id)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax . . . and use it.  Also, the `GROUP BY` columns should match the unaggregated `SELECT` columns:

```
SELECT p.Property_Address, COUNT(s.Survey_ID) AS SurveyCount
FROM Property p JOIN
     Survey s
     ON p.Property_ID = s.Property_ID
GROUP by p.Property_Address;
```

Notice that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.  Finally, if you want all properties, even those without surveys, then use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.Property_Address, COUNT(s.Survey_ID) AS SurveyCount
FROM Property p LEFT JOIN
     Survey s
     ON p.Property_ID = s.Property_ID
GROUP by p.Property_Address;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I can see now where I went wrong and how to avoid the same mistake in future.